# How to create a function that acts the same way as the method includes()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that would work the same way as the method includes by using two parameters. Right now it only works with methods that would return false, however, true doesn't work and I can't figure out why it doesn't go into the if statement.

```
function includes(array, value) {
    for(let i =0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

includes([1,2,3,4,5], 3);
```

Comment: array.indexOf(3) != -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `returning` a result on the very first iteration of the loop, thereby terminating the function before you've checked every element.

You can easily fix this by only returning `true` if you do find it, and otherwise just continuing the loop, returning `false` only after the loop if it wasn't found:

```
function includes(array, value) {
    for(let i =0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method from Javascript and do like this:

```js
function includes(array, value) {
    return array.indexOf(value) !== -1
}

console.log(includes([1,2,3,4,5], 3));
```

This is a short and simple solution that also supports IE9 whereas [Javascript's includes method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `doesn't in any IE` as per MDN Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use includes method in the includes function?

```
function includes(array, value) {
  return array.includes(value)
}
```

But I don't see what is the point of having a function like that.

If you need a function that will mimic includes method:

```
function includes(array, value) {
  for(e of array) {
    if (e == value) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Instead of for-of loop, you can use other array methods like find, indexOf, filter, but using for loop is better idea in terms of performance because you can break early. It can be important when you work on huge data.